# Using the home landline throught Ubuntu - is it possible?

Tags: modem, phone, pstn

Say I have a usb fax modem on my laptop..and I connect it to my home telephone landline, is there an option to receive and send calls through Ubuntu, using said line?

Comment: As long as there is a driver for the Fax Modem I don't see why not.